# Angular Js : TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: rest, salesforce

So , I have a angular code which integrates with salesforce. It makes a rest call to salesforce to get some records.

Now in the sucess handler of that rest call I am trying to open a new div with a seprate controller and I get the error :

TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null

If I try and call this from outside of the success handler I do not get this error. But since my data gets queried inside my success handler I need to user it there.

Here is my code :

```
    filterservice.getproductlist(successHandler,errorHandler);

function successHandler(data) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        defer.resolve(data);
    });
}

defer.promise.then(function(data){
    console.log('In not');
   filterservice.setproductlist(data);
}).then(function(){
        console.log('open then');
        $scope.opendetailwindow(
        'sellingAreas/sellingAreasFilters/selectProducts.tpl.html',
        'showProducts');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

what that means is the element that you're attaching events to was not found.

consider this jquery:

```
$('.something').on('click', doSomeCallback );
```

This code will return an array, and for each array item, it will apply `doSomeCallback` as the callback function. This is how jquery protects the code writer from having null errors when the array has a length of zero.

In pure javascript, you'd say something like this:

```
var element = document.getElementById('someElement');
element.addEventListener('click', doSomeCallback);
```

But if `element` is not found, then `element` will equal `null`, which then has no properties or class methods... one of which would be `addEventListener`.

In your code, you're using `defer` which is presumably built on top of the `addEventListener` method in javascript.

Thus, whatever element you attached your `defer` events / methods to is not always being found in the DOM. so make sure that you figure out why that element is not being found, and that will stop you from having that error.